# What is the difference between "vector::operator=" and "vector::assign"?

Tags: c++11, stdvector, assignment-operator, initializer-list

What is the difference between `.operator=(std::initializer_list<T>)` and `.assign(std::initializer_list<T>)` in the `std::vector` class? Do they do the same?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign

What is the whole idea of having both `assign` and assigment operator `operator=`? Is the fact that `assign` member can accept more than one argument? (However `std::initializer_list` is a single argument.)

Answer (score 1):

Their return types differ: the operator returns the vector by reference,  `assign` returns void.

Technically,  the spec for assignment from initializer_list says the elements are "assigned or destroyed ", while assign from initializer_list "replaces elements " ([Table 87](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#4)), but that seems immaterial: actual implementations of one just call the other (I checked libc++ and libstdc++)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the whole idea of having both `assign` and assignment operator `operator=`

You can pass a pair of iterators (range) into `assign` but not into `operator=`.